# matplotlib not displaying image on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, jupyter

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and coding in jupyter notebook using anaconda2.7 and everything else is up to date . Today I was coding, every thing worked fine. I closed the notebook and when I reopened it, every thing worked fine except that the image was not being displayed.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import skimage
from skimage import data
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%pylab inline

img = data.camera()
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
```

this is the code i am using, a really simple one but doesn't display the image

```
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0xaf7017ac>
```

this is displayed in the output area
please help

Answer (score 38):

You need to tell matplotlib to actually show the image. Add this at the end of your segment:

```
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 16):

To show image in Jupyter Notebook by matplotlib, one should use the `%matplotlib inline` magic command and `plt.show()`.
As for your code, adding `plt.show()` after `plt.imshow()` expression will make the image shown.

Answer (score 11):

If using the `inline` backend, you just need to call `plt.show()`.

If you are using the `notebook` backend (`%matplotlib notebook`), then you should call `plt.figure()` before `plt.imshow(img)`. This is especially important if you wish to use interactive figures!

Answer (score 1):

change kernel from xpython to original python kernel